# How to center dynamic buttons in a groupbox Windows form application

Tags: c#

can you tell me please how can i horizontal center dynamic buttons inside a groupbox? Is there something like this textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center ?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button[,] Buttons;  

        Buttons = new Button[4, 4];
        int c,r;

        for (r = 0; r < 4; r++) for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            Buttons[r, c] = new Button();
            Buttons[r, c].Parent = groupBox1;
            Buttons[r, c].Top = 50 + r * 25;
            Buttons[r, c].Left = 30 + c * 40;
            Buttons[r, c].Width = 40;                     
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover both x and y axis centering:

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[4, 4];
        int c, r;

        int xOffset = (groupBox1.Width - (40 * 4)) / 2;
        int yOffset = (groupBox1.Height - 25 * 4) / 2;

        for (r = 0; r < 4; r++) for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
            {
                buttons[r, c] = new Button {Parent = groupBox1, Top = yOffset + r*25, Left = xOffset + c*40, Width = 40};
            }
        buttons[0, 0].Text = "1";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate an offset from left border of the groupbox.
Given 4 buttons of size 40 you have 160 pixels of space occupied by your buttons.
If the width of the groupbox is 400 pixels then

```
 int leftOffset = (groupbox1.Width - (40 * numberOfButtons)) / 2; // (400 - 160) / 2
```

now use this offset

```
   Buttons[r, c].Left = leftOffset + c * 40;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fow Layout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) adding the buttons like a simple Panel.